# How to set advanced FileVersionInfo fields?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-assembly, fileversioninfo

How can the advanced `FileVersionInfo` fields like `IsPreRelease`, `IsSpecialBuild`, `SpecialBuild` be affected prior build process to show custom values?

I'm only aware of:

- Assembly Information button in VS Project properties on Application tab.
- AssemblyInfo.cs file and `Assembly*Attribute` classes.
- Application.manifest file.

Unfortunately it seems like these ways cannot be used to setup the additional fields. Is there any possibility to separate the whole version info in any editable form and put it to the build system prior the creation of new build? Any clue?

Comment: Generating a custom file version resource requires Project + Properties, Application tab, Resource file radio button.  The effort of creating and (especially) maintaining the .res file heavily outstrips the usefulness of tinkering with these properties.  Nobody actually ever looks at them, they are not visible in the Details property sheet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8914810/17034

Comment: Thank you. I have an effective way, how to display them, so the lack of windows functionality does not bother me. Anyway it looks like it will be simpler to leave the resources untouched and use own way for tagging the assembly.