# Additional icons in .EXE?

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I'm trying to add additional icons to my program (for reference in Windows Explorer, for example, MyProg.exe,1).

I've tried/followed *many* guides that supposedly will add the extra icons, but none of them have worked, and alot seem to be for older version of .NET - I'm using 2013.

I'm not looking to embed the icons and reference them in my program, but to embed them and allow Windows Explorer to choose an icon other than the program's icon, like shell32.dll or imgres.dll have several icons to choose from.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @jradich1234 I'm not _entirely_ sure that's correct. Anecdotally, I seem to recall some executables having multiple icons back in the day, but I must admit I haven't noticed it post-XP (not that I've been looking)

Comment: This is not simple to do for a VB.NET project, the IDE does support compilig with a custom /win32resource option.  You'll have to build from the command line, that's pretty little joy.  The procedure to do it for a C# project is shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8914810/17034).