# embed .res file as a native win 32 resource into c# application

Tags: c#, winapi, embedded-resource

i want to embed win32 resource into c# application, but i don`t know how.
Somone on CodeProject said that it is impossible and suggest to use resource hacker:

[code project article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3348/Embed-Win32-resources-in-C-programs)

I tryed it and it is working good.

but the problem is that i want to add this resources in visual studio using code (or some ide parameters or settings) without third party programms like respurce hacker.

also i know that when i create an c# application, somehow it recives standart resources like ["version info" and "Manifest"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWhfl.png)

so i`m asking is it still impossible to do this, or actualy possible because applications have some standart resources.

Comment: It is supported, Project > Properties > Application tab, "Resource file" setting.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914810/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported, Project > Properties > Application tab, "Resource file" setting.