# WPF JumpList Icon not populating

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, jump-list

I have set up a JumpList in my WPF Application.

The JumpList is fully functional apart from the Icons are not displaying, this is what I am seeing in my Taskbar:

[image]

Here is the code I have to create the JumpTask:

```
using System.Windows.Shell;

public JumpTask BuildJumpTask
{
    get
    {
        return new JumpTask
        {
            Arguments = Argument,
            ApplicationPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location,
            Description = GenerateDescription(),
            IconResourcePath = GetIconPath(),
            Title = Name
        };
    }
}

Private string GetIconPath()
{
    return Type switch
    {
        JumpListItemType.About => Path.GetFullPath(@"Assets\Icons\JumpList\About.ico"),
        JumpListItemType.Help => Path.GetFullPath(@"Assets\Icons\JumpList\Help.ico"),
        JumpListItemType.Quit => Path.GetFullPath(@"Assets\Icons\JumpList\Quit.ico"),
        JumpListItemType.Settings => Path.GetFullPath(@"Assets\Icons\JumpList\Settings.ico"),
        JumpListItemType.Sign_Out => Path.GetFullPath(@"Assets\Icons\JumpList\Sign_Out.ico"),
            _ => null!
    };
}
```

All .ico files are being output to the expected directory,

I am using the following Properties for them files:

**Build Action:** Embedded resource *(I have also tried Content)*

**Copy to Output Directory:** Copy if newer

Comment: You didn't read the documentation for `IconResourcePath`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumptask.iconresourcepath?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 - you cannot specify an image filename, you have to specify the path to a Win32 PE with embedded Win32 `ICON` resources. You also need to pass `IconResourceIndex` too.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `JumpTask.IconResourcePath` states (emphasis mine):

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumptask.iconresourcepath
>
> The path to a resource that contains the icon. The default is `null`.
> [...]
> An icon used with a `JumpTask` **must be available as a native resource**.

Therefore you cannot specify the path to a PNG file for the JumpList icon - this makes sense because Win32 Icons support multiple sizes (e.g. high DPI, large icons, etc) instead of single images - you can't do that with a PNG file.

*Fortunately* you don't need to fire-up VisualC++ just to build a `.dll` file containing a handful of icons: this QA has instructions for how to add multiple `.ico` files as native `ICON`/`ICONDIRECTORY` resources: [Adding multiple Icons (Win32-Resource) to .NET-Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913018/adding-multiple-icons-win32-resource-to-net-application) - Note that the C# compiler `-win32icon` option only lets you specify a single icon (as the *application icon* of the `.exe` file), making it useless for this purpose.

Don't forget to ensure you include suitable icon artwork at 16x16, 24x24, and 32x32 to ensure your jump-list items look acceptable on non-96dpi displays.

Also note that Win32 *native resources* are an entirely distinct concept from .NET `.resources`/`.resx` - and also separate from WPF/XAML `<ResourceDictionary>` objects too.

Comment: So is that a case of adding a ResourceDictionary or is it more in-depth than that?

Comment: @Richard.Gale `ResourceDictionary` is for WPF/XAML, and is entirely unrelated to Win32 PE native resources.